# Can someone identify this girl in Nurarihyon no Mago?

Tags: nurarihyon-no-mago

I left the title ambiguous as my question is slightly spoiler-ish.

> Who is this girl who killed Nura Rikuo's father, Nura Rihan?
>
>  [image: This tiny girl in the picture.]

Did they actually say who she was? Or am I right that they never flat out said it?

> Hagoromo Gitsune was still sealed, so it couldn't have been her. But I know it has something to do with Hagoromo Gitsune's curse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She is...

> young **Yamabuki Otome** (Hagoromo Gitsune's host).
>
>  [image: Yamabuki Otome]

who is actually...

> Rihan first wife.
>  [Abe no Seimei and Sanmoto Gorōzaemon brought her back to life in her younger form](http://nurarihyonnomago.wikia.com/wiki/Yamabuki_Otome#8_Years_Ago) to become Hagoromo Gitsune's host.